# Answering without real experience

Tags: discussion, answers

I am new to the academia and read a lot of how to be a good student/researcher and teacher.

This said, I really have no *real* experience in some questions on Academia.SE but I do have a sense on how things supposed to work. For example, I answered [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5655/what-are-the-different-roles-between-pc-member-and-reviewer) without being  ever a PC. **My question: is it valid in Academia.SE to do so?**

Comment: your answer there is actually correct !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to be an expert in on aspect to answer about it, any answer is (potentially) valid. If your answer is considered of good quality from the community, it might be upvoted, if the quality is low, it might be downvoted (and even deleted, if it's really bad). It can also be edited by others, if they believe it can improve the answer.

Of course, the more facts/sources you can bring to your answer, the better it is!